# MongoDB - use numericOrdering in aggregation do mongo slow

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have this issue, when I run my query normal, everything works 100% perfect but when I try to add `numericOrdering` it will not.

```
aggregation = [
    {'$match': {'store': 'fourcom', 'closed': 0}}, 
    {'$lookup': {
        'from': 'ordre_open', 
        'localField': 'reference_number', 
        'foreignField': 'order_number', 
        'as': 'ordre_open'
    }}, 
    {'$lookup': {
        'from': 'ordre_backend_open', 
        'localField': 'reference_number', 
        'foreignField': 'ordre-id', 
        'as': 'ordre_backend'
    }}, 
    {'$project': {
        '_id': 1, 
        'store': 1, 
        'order_number': 1, 
        'document_number': 1, 
        'reference_number': 1, 
        'document_date': 1, 
        'invoice_group': 1, 
        'account': 1, 
        'name': 1, 
        'our_ref': 1, 
        'your_ref': 1, 
        'payment': 1, 
        'vat': 1, 
        'total_price': 1, 
        'currency': 1, 
        'department': 1, 
        'closed': 1, 
        'deleted': 1, 
        'arch': 1, 
        'locations': 1, 
        'lines.price': 1, 
        'lines.qty': 1, 
        'ordre_open._id': 1, 
        'ordre_open.order_number': 1, 
        'ordre_open.closed': 1, 
        'ordre_open.deleted': 1, 
        'ordre_open.type': 1, 
        'ordre_open.arch': 1, 
        'ordre_open.fcomputer_synced': 1, 
        'ordre_backend.ordre-id': 1, 
        'ordre_backend.error': 1, 
        'ordre_backend.done': 1, 
        'ordre_backend.cancel': 1
    }}, 
    {'$sort': {'order_number': 1}}, 
    {'$skip': 0}, 
    {'$limit': 1000}
]
mongodb_limit = 1000

resualt = db.command('aggregate', 'ordre_purchase_open', pipeline=aggregation, explain=False, cursor={
                'batchSize': mongodb_limit
            })
```

but when I decide to to sort like we humans do and add

```
collation={
    'numericOrdering': True,
    'locale': "da"
}
```

its going total wrong, my query go down and will not work as I expect. I have used `numericOrdering` many time before but this time is first time in `db.command` by using `aggregate`.

I hope someone can explain what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Could you format your source code so that it is more readable? There are also  quite a lot of typos. If you could fix them, that would enhance the readability, too. Finally, show us the complete code. You just define the variable `collation`, but you do not show us, how it is used.

Comment: Index the collection and sort it on the first stage.